# Asp.NET Core authentication failing

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to add authentication to my app, frontend VueJS backend Asp.NET core 2.1 but I'm failing to get it to actually authenticate in the end.

Setting up the authentication in Asp.NET:

```
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mysecret");
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

My UserService is mocked to return the same hardcoded user always.

The frontend seems to be sending the correct token it gets from the backend when logging in:

[image]

But, I'm still getting rejected when calling authorized endpoints:

[image]

The server reports the following logs:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action DnaBackend.Controllers.DnaController.UploadFile (DnaBackend) in 32.891ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 41.847ms 401 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLIDVBUA1Q5P", Request id "0HLIDVBUA1Q5P:00000003": the application completed without reading the entire request body.`

Any ideas why this is failing?
I'm using CORS too, if that makes any difference(?).

Login endpoint looks like so:

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromForm]LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {

        var user = _userService.Authenticate(loginRequest.Username, loginRequest.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        // return basic user info (without password) and token to store client side
        return Ok(new LoginResponse(user.Id, user.Username, user.FirstName, user.LastName, tokenString));
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was that i had put `UseAuthorization` before `UseAuthentication`.

Please make sure these methods are in the following order:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: I must have spent a day trying to figure out what was wrong with my authentication scheme.

Comment: In My Case I add [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]  In All Controller.

Answer (score 7):

This turned out to be a case of just missing an `app.UseAuthentication()` in startup.cs

Not completely super intuivitve by ASP.NET to require this when you have also configured services using `AddAuthentication`.

So if anyone else have the same problem, you know why now :-)