# WsFederation with .net core not preserving claims

Tags: c#, .net-core, ws-federation

I am attempting to use ws-federation with .net core to handle single sign on. I have been able to receive a security token from my federated service, but the claims retrieved from the security token are not getting added to the user that's getting authenticated against, and even though a cookie is being written to after the token has been validated, the user does not get an updated set if identities or claims, leaving the user in a state where HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always set to false.

My ConfigureServies:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            services.AddControllersWithViews();


            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }
            ).AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration();
                configuration.Issuer = "http://localhost/STSSpike2/V1";
                configuration.TokenEndpoint = "http://localhost/STSSpike/V1";
                options.Configuration = configuration;
                options.Wtrealm = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp/Test";
                options.Wreply = "http://localhost/STSAwareApp/signin-wsfed";
                options.SecurityTokenHandlers.Add(new FakeTokenValidator());

                options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.Exception.ToString());
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.Failure);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnSecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.ProtocolMessage);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                options.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "TestStsAuth1";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = val =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("validated");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = denied =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("validated");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToReturnUrl = redirect =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("validated");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnSignedIn = signedIn =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Signedin");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnSigningIn = signingIn =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("signing in");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddLogging(
                builder =>
                {
                builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Trace)
                       .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Trace)
                       .AddConsole();
                });
        }
```

In the code above, the Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated and CookieOptions.Events.OnSignedIn point to the Principal that are derived from the security token returned from ws-federation. However, the HttpContext.User is never updated with the new identity. So once the security token is validated, the client repeatedly calls back to the federated server to request a token, with the only log messages being:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem came from my Configure call in that I called UseAuthorization before I called UseAuthentication. [This answer was the key to finding out what teh issue was.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585194/55913)